# How do I add an organization in Trello?

Tags: trello

I received an email explaining how to add an organization yet I don't have that option in the "add" drop-down. Is there an upgraded version that would include this?

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve your problem a screenshot would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

1. [Create a team](http://help.trello.com/article/705-creating-a-new-team) by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> on the top left side of your Trello Header
2. [Invite people to a team](http://help.trello.com/article/715-inviting-people-to-an-organization) by clicking the <kbd>Members</kbd> tab in the Team's profile. Then you can choose between adding a single person, bulk adding, or linking google apps.

Note:

- Only an admin can add members
- Teams don't require a paid account

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer. Thanks!